# can i use bluetooth or any other built-in device hardware in my phone in pwa

Tags: bluetooth, gps, iot, web-component, progressive-web-apps

I am new to Web and I started PWA (Progressive Web Apps) to build stuff in web. And the question is, I want to use the **GPS module and Bluetooth** in my phone, Is there a way to communicate it? and use it at the web.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access in Geo Location(for GPS) and Bluetooth in PWA. What you have to note is not all browsers support all the hardware access API.. especially Bluetooth. Geo location should work in most part. So you have to have backfall for all such access so users will have alternate or atleast a message saying they need to use specific browsers and version if they need to use your site.  You can check what is supported and what is not by visiting this site in the targetterd device -browser - https://whatwebcando.today/